How to get logits from trained tensorflow model (for softmax temperature scaling)
I have a trained TensorFlow classification model (52 classes).
I didn't built the model (I just load it with it's weights)
the 3 last layers are:
model.add(LSTM(70, return_sequences=False, unroll=True)
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(52, activation='softmax'))

I want to get the logits (values before the softmax) in order to calibrate the model (with softmax temperature scaling ) .
How can I get those logits ?
If I will try this way:
probabilities = model.predict(input_data)
logits = tf.math.log(probabilities)

I will get wrong logits (because softmax divide each logit with the sum of exp logits)
If I will try this way:
logits_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
logits = logits_layer_model.predict(input_data)

In this way, there is no consideration of the weights of the last layer.
How should I get the logits ?

just do this when creating your model instead:
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input((n_timesteps, n_features))) # It is good practice to use an Input layer.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(70, return_sequences=False, unroll=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(52))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))

That way you can recover the logits with:
logits_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.layers[0].input, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
logits = logits_layer_model.predict(input_data)

You can check it yourself, the model output will be the same:
tf.random.set_seed(0)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input((n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(70, return_sequences=False, unroll=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(52, activation="softmax"))

model.save_weights("model.weights.h5")

model_input = tf.random.uniform([1, n_timesteps, n_features], 0., 1.)

print(model.predict(model_input))

model.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.linear
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))

print(model.predict(model_input))

For just loading the weights:
new_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input((n_timesteps, n_features)))
new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(70, return_sequences=False, unroll=True))
new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50))
new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(52)) # Same as activation="linear".

new_model.load_weights("model.weights.h5")

print(new_model.predict(model_input))


I didnt create the model (I just load it with its weights)

You can still use the last 3 lines of the 3rd snippet of code to edit the model's activation layer. As a matter of fact, since you're only loading the weights you don't even need to add the Activation layer the way I did.

I have edited the answer (added a 4th snippet of code), hopefully it is a bit clearer. If you're exclusively loading the weights then you don't even have to pass an activation function to the last layer at all.
